# Can't delete "^M\n" from a .txt file

Tags: python, bash

I'm generating a .txt from a SQL database. But for some reason, some of my data is not just plain text.

My .txt file looks like this:

```
PC001|1FSTFJ|BE21|Rooftop 
PC002|JVQ2F9|BE22|Basement
PC003|JY1035W1|BE22|Basement^M\n
```

I tried some Python and Bash scripts with the help of gpt, but it doesn't work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file_path="file.txt"

sed -i 's/\^M\n//g' "$file_path"
```

This script literally does nothing, and I don't understand why.

And the Python script:

```py
def clean_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

        cleaned_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            # Diviser la ligne en champs, en supposant qu'ils sont séparés par '|'
            fields = line.strip().split('|')
            
            # Nettoyer chaque champ individuellement
            cleaned_fields = [field.rstrip('M').strip() for field in fields]

            # Recombiner les champs nettoyés en une seule ligne
            cleaned_line = '|'.join(cleaned_fields)
            cleaned_lines.append(cleaned_line)

        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            # Écrit toutes les lignes nettoyées, avec un saut de ligne approprié après chaque ligne
            file.write('\n'.join(cleaned_lines))

        print("Le fichier a été nettoyé avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {str(e)}")

file_path = 'file.txt'

clean_file(file_path)
```

I also tried with `.replace`, because I saw that it could work, but it didn't for me.

```py
def clean_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

        cleaned_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            # Diviser la ligne en champs, en supposant qu'ils sont séparés par '|'
            fields = line.split('|')
            
            # Nettoyer chaque champ individuellement
            cleaned_fields = [field.replace('M\n', '').strip() for field in fields]

            # Recombiner les champs nettoyés en une seule ligne
            cleaned_line = '|'.join(cleaned_fields).rstrip('\n')
            cleaned_lines.append(cleaned_line)

        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write('\n'.join(cleaned_lines))

        print("Le fichier a été nettoyé avec succès.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {str(e)}")

file_path = 'file.txt'

clean_file(file_path)
```

With both Python scripts, I get this kind of result:

```
PC001|1FSTFJ|BE21|Rooftop 
PC002|JVQ2F9|BE22|Basement
PC003|JY1035W1|BE23|Basement
\n
PC004|FFJSFH43|BE24|Rooftop
```

So there's not more `^M` but there's still the `\n`, and it's on the next line.

Comment: Tried the `dos2unix` util?

Comment: @Friedrich No I didn't, I will look into it

Comment: BTW, `^M` is not two characters, it's one character and stands for ASCII 0x0D aka `\r` or "carriage return". What you see is a CRLF line ending.

Comment: @Friedrich Yea I figured it out while  doing research and making the script. But what I found strange is the fact that the "^M" was colored when opening txt file with nano editor, but "\n" isn't. But the script managed to delete the "^M" but not the "\n" ....

Comment: Would be nice to see a [mre] and how the file was created. Maybe you managed to get a literal backslash into your file. Hard to tell from over here...

Comment: Do you **relly** want to delete the newline as well? In general it is a bad idea to remove the newline from the last line of a file, because many utilities rely on the assumption, that every line (including the last one) ends in a newline.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, because the file will be used by another software that a colleague uses.  All I know is that he needs the informations to be plain text. He needs basement and not basement^M\n

Comment: While I don't get how the requirement of having _plain text_ is related to the way the last line ends, if you are sure that you want to do this, look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-remove-trailing-newline) for how to do this easily. For your case, perhaps the solution using `head` is the simplest.

Comment: "Plain text" ends in a linefeed otherwise it's not a valid line (and so not a valid text file) per POSIX. Is that `\n` in your input literally the 2 characters ```\``` and `n` or is it meant to represent a LineFeed character `\n`? Is the `^M` 2 characters `^` and `M` or does it represent a CarriageReturn character `control-M` aka `\r`?

Comment: If the `\n` represents a linefeed, though, then how are you seeing 3 lines of input with nothing at the end of the first 2?

Comment: Run `cat file` and `cat -vE file` and then [edit] your question to show the output of both commands so we can see what your input file really contains.

Comment: Run `xxd file.txt`, and add the output to your question. That way we'll see each byte (with hex code) in the file.

Comment: (which version of `gpt` recommended these code samples?! (-:? (yikes!) ) . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this first :

```
sed 's/\r\\n//' file.txt | vim -
# :q! to exit from vim
```

If the result looks fine, change the file with :

```
sed -i 's/\r\\n//' file.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Piping to vim is a debugging step to visually check that the output is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is an in-restrospect explanation why your original attempt `sed -i 's/\^M\n//g' "$file_path"` didn't work. It also explains how to fix your sed and Python attempts.

Your sed command `s/\^M\n//g` replaces (in each line) all occurrences of `^` (hex 5e) + `M` (hex 4d) + newline (hex 0a) with an empty string. This can't possibly work, because by the time `sed` runs its commands, the newline (hex 0a) is already removed from the end of the line (by sed), so the regexp won't match.

In fact, you had something else at the end of your lines: carriage-return (hex 0d) + backslash (hex 5c) + `n` (hex 6e). This can be replaced with an empty string using the sed command `s/\r\\n//`, as written in the answer by Philippe. The equivalent Python command: `line = line.replace('\r\\n', '')`.

Such search-and-replace should be easy. Here are the typical causes of confusion which make it longer to get it right:

- Most terminals, text editors and command-line tools are terrible at showing you exactly what bytes the input file contains. To make sure, start from a hexdump (e.g. with `xxd file.txt`). Remember: on Unix newline is hex 0a, on other systems lines are separated by carriage-return (hex 0d) + newline (hex 0a). It's useul to know that tab is hex 09, space is hex 20, printable ASCII characters are between hex 21 and hex 7e (inclusive).
- Copy-pasting text file contents to a question on StackOverflow is also terrible at showing others eactly what bytes the input file contains. To fix that, copy-paste the output of `xxd file.txt`.
- sed splits the input file on newline (hex 0a), and feeds each line (without the trailing newline) separately to the command, and then it prints the output and a newline (hex 0a). Thus the sed `s/.../.../` command never sees the newline (hex 0a) byte.
- On Unix, Python `.readline()` and `for` loop on the file split the input file on newline (hex 0a) or on others, depending on the 2nd argument you passed to `open`. Even after the split, it keeps the newline (hex 0a) byte in the input line string.
- On Unix, Perl splits on newline (hex 0a), and it keeps the newline (hex 0a)  byte in the input line string.
- For regexp replacement (e.g. `s/.../.../` in sed), you have to specify some bytes (characters) with backslash: newline (hex 0a) is `\n`, carriage-return (hex 0d) is `\r`, `^` is `\^`, `$` is `\$`, `\` is `\\` etc.
- The shell may process backslashes (`\`) in the command-line and in scripts. To avoid that, put the command within single quotes. You did it correctly: `sed -i 's/.../.../g'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` before `n`, like so:

```bash
sed -i 's/\^M\\n//g' "$file_path"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using Perl (without the leading `$`s):

```
$ echo 'PC001|1FSTFJ|BE21|Rooftop ' >file.txt
$ echo 'PC002|JVQ2F9|BE22|Basement' >>file.txt
$ echo 'PC003|JY1035W1|BE22|Basement^M\n' >>file.txt
$ perl -pe 'chomp; s@\r$@@; s@\\n$@@; s@\r$@@; s@\\r$@@; s@\^M$@@; s@\s*$@\n@' <file.txt >file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt
PC001|1FSTFJ|BE21|Rooftop
PC002|JVQ2F9|BE22|Basement
PC003|JY1035W1|BE22|Basement
```

The conversion command is the one starting with `perl` in the middle above.

If it doesn't work for you, then your actual `file.txt` contains something else: different from what you posted in the question. In this case, add the output of `xxd file.txt` to your question, so that we can see what exactly your file contains.